# Why django TemplateSyntaxError is raised in here?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Im tring to iterate through context of my view and get 'ga:deviceCategory' values only , the code that I'm running in HTML is:

```
<div class="card-body">
  {% for i in pvdc %}
    <p>{{ i.get('ga:deviceCategory') }}</p>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

My view in django is :

```
def dashboard(request):
  context = {'pvdc': [{'ga:deviceCategory': 'desktop', 'ga:pageviews': 673, 'ga:avgSessionDuration': 53.4447946},
{'ga:deviceCategory': 'mobile', 'ga:pageviews': 2373, 'ga:avgSessionDuration': 69.62674418604651},
{'ga:deviceCategory': 'tablet', 'ga:pageviews': 322, 'ga:avgSessionDuration': 26.205426356589147}]}
  return render(request, 'user/index.html', context)
```

The syntax error that I receive is:
Could not parse the remainder: '('ga:deviceCategory')' from 'i.get('ga:deviceCategory')'

[image]

what is the problem here and how can i get the values?

Answer (score 0):

data is not rendering from for loop so you need to remove the get from

{{ i.get('ga:deviceCategory') }}

```
<div class="card-body">
  {% for i in pvdc %}
    <p>{{ i.'ga:deviceCategory'}}</p>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Tarun, however, it's still raising the same TemplateSyntaxError

Answer (score 0):

There could be another better way but for now try this
This error is coming because of `:` this.
While passing the data to you in `Dictionary` you have to change the `key` name in your `dictionary`.

```
context = {'pvdc': [{'ga_deviceCategory': 'desktop', 'ga:pageviews': 673, 'ga:avgSessionDuration': 53.4447946}
```

and access into your template like this

```
<div class="card-body">
  {% for i in pvdc %}
    <p>{{ i.0 }}</p>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: it's still raising the same TemplateSyntaxError with 'ga_deviceCategory' edited. any suggestions?